# Azure KQL query to display list of VMs which were not patch for since 1 months

Tags: azure, vm

Is there a KQL query to get a list of VMs which are not patched since last month. Below is the sample I have

```
Update
| where Classification in ("Security Updates", "Critical Updates")
| where UpdateState == 'Needed' and Optional == false and Approved == true
| summarize count() by Classification, Computer, _ResourceId
// This query requires the Security or Update solutions
```

How to apply the filter to just show the ones which are due since one month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve that

```
Update
//|where OSType != "Linux" and UpdateState == "Needed" and Optional == "false"
| where Classification in ("Security Updates", "Critical Updates") 
| where PublishedDate <= ago(30d)
| where startofday(TimeGenerated) == startofday(now())
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, Title, KBID, Classification, MSRCSeverity, PublishedDate, _ResourceId
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| summarize any(KBID) by KBID, Title, Computer
```